# mysql not started automatically upon server reboot

Tags: mysql, unix, solaris, permissions

mysql not started @ server boot automatically but I can start manually as long as log as user "mysql" by using "/etc/init.d/mysql.server" the error I got on the log is

```
110809  9:16:21  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

so my question is how I can give permission for "root" and mysql start @ boot.

```
     Note - ./ibdata1 and it's directory are own by mysql
```

Thanks in advance for any help. p.

Comment: what are the current permissions of the ibdata1 file?

Comment: 660 is the current permission on the file. the data directory is 750

Comment: `ls -ld /path/to/<MySQL_datadir>`? I'm not familiar with Solaris, so is there anything similar to SELinux or AppArmor in Linux? Did you try to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Your ibdata1 file should be owned by `mysql`, and read writeable (600)

Make sure your server is running as user `mysql` as described by [the user option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_user)

Comment: Thanks for the response, ibdata1 file own by "mysql" and has permission "660" and the sql by user "mysql" I think my issue is why not root unable to start my sql.